# Reference data look-up in Entity Framework 4.2 code first

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I’m putting together a code first model that has a lot of reference data.  This model is based around applications, servers, and build deployments.  Thus, there are a lot of many to many relationships.  The pain that I’m feeling is that new records are being placed in the entity tables which I’m attempting to use as reference data.  For example, we have a list of servers.  I only want to see a server ONCE in the table.  For all the entities referring to that server, I want them to use that row.  The same can be said of my ServerRoles and Applications tables.   These tables contain static data that I’m seeding and should rarely change.

I know I could solve this with look-ups and hand wiring, but I would think EF would comprehend this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Entity Framework code-first you can create an **immutable object** with *protected parameter less constructor* and *private set* properties.

It works for sure with EF 5 Beta.

[Update]

Tested also with EF 4.3.1, it works.

```
public class Nation
{
    protected Nation() {}

    public Nation(Guid id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }

    public Guid Id { get; private set; }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Matteo!  That works for some of my scenarios, but what about some of the scenarios where I want to include some of the data in the relationship?

Comment: Create a third class where you have the entity with the properties of the relation and the value object.